# Element is not clickable at point

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

soy nuevo en este mundo apasionante, pero no logro dar solución a un problema que tengo:
Tengo una pagina web con este HTML, en el cual cuando paso el mouse por encima se convierte en un hipervínculo.
El HTML en cuestión es éste:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
 <a class="panel panel-default" role="button">
  <div class="media p-a-2">
   <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="roboto-font bold h5">DOMICILIO FISCAL ELECTRÓNICO</h3>
     <p class="text-muted">Accedé a tus comunicaciones electrónicas. Consultá el estado de los mensajes y notificaciones.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Lo que necesito es hacer click en ese link, cosa que me es imposible poder lograrlo. Mi código para ubicarlo en Selenium es:

```
    String Ruta6="//p[contains(text(),'Accedé a tus comunicaciones electrónicas. Consultá')] ";
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15)); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(Ruta6)))  ;
    WebElement txtBuscador =driver.findElement(By.xpath(Ruta6));
    txtBuscador.click();
```

Ruego ayuda urgente, debe ser una estupidez pero no logro dar solución al problema.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La pagina web que estas revisando con Selenium es tuya?
a lo que voy es, si te es posible ponerle Id a los elementos de html de la pagina

Comment: Como estas, no, no es una página mía. Es de afip.

Comment: Revisa este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth) 
es para python pero, se acerca mucho a lo que parece que necesitas

Comment: Genial. Muchísimas gracias. Lo miro y te cuento